# How can i escape double quotes from a string in php?

Tags: php, string, escaping, double-quotes

I've been trying to solve this but no luck. This is my code.

```
       $replace1 =str_replace('hreflang=\"'.$arr['variantslang1hid'].'\"     lang=\"'.$arr['variantslang1hid'].'\"','hreflang=\"'.$arr['variantslang1'].'\" lang=\"'.$arr['variantslang1'].'\"',$replace1);
```

It should replace but no. I'm not escaping "" properly. How can i solve this? Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use single quotes, you don't need to escape double quotes, '"' is what you want.

Comment: to elaborate, in single quoted strings, you only need to escape single quotes, and in double quoted strings, you only need to escape double quotes.